# How to read convert the given text into buffer than Add the text ‘hello world’ to the given input and return the final output as a buffer

Tags: node.js, string, append, buffer

This is What I've tried

```
    const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
        let addBuffer = (text) => {
            const textBuffer = Buffer.from(text);
            textBuffer.write('hello World ');
            return textBuffer;
        };
```

I want to add the new string i.e. 'Hello World' to the end of the given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Buffer.concat](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) for this purpose, this allows you to concatenate any number of Buffers together:

```
let addBuffer = (text) => {
    return Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(text), Buffer.from('hello world')]);
};

console.log(addBuffer('Some text - ').toString("utf8"));
```

Comment: I tried using Buffer.concat just as you suggested long before too but the compiler in that assignment environment doesn't accept my answer even though it works just fine in my environment too. Anyway, I'll will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh yes, I wonder if it was an earlier version of Node.js that didn't support this keyword..